# Consistency of a particular theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Take a first order language with Parameter:

Constant Symbol: $\emptyset$

Equality Relation and Belonging to Relation as Predicate Symbol

Now take theory in this first order language with axioms:

1. $(\forall x)(\forall y)\Bigg((x=y) \longleftrightarrow \Big((\forall z)(z \in x \longleftrightarrow z \in y)\Big)\Bigg)$
2. $(\forall x)(\forall y)\Bigg((x\neq y) \longleftrightarrow \Big((\exists z)\big(z \in x \land z \notin y)\lor (z \notin x \land z \in y)\big)\Big)\Bigg)$
3. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)\Big(\big(x=y) \land (x \in z)\big) \longrightarrow (y \in z)\Big)$
4. $(\forall x)(x \notin \emptyset)$

**Question:** Is this theory consistent?

**Explanation of terms:** Consistency means prove there doesn't exist $\phi$ such that this theory proves $\phi$ as well as $\neg\phi$.

Consistency I am not taking whether there exist model of this theory in set theory.

Comment: **Hint:** There is a model with one element.

Comment: @Sushil Regarding "Consistency means prove there doesn't exist $\varphi$ such that this theory proves $\varphi$ as well as $\lnot\varphi$. Consistency I am not taking whether there exist model of this theory in set theory." First-order logic is sound for its usual semantics. A consequence of this is that if we can produce a model of a theory $T$, then $T$ is consistent. Indeed, if we could prove $\varphi$ and $\lnot\varphi$ from $T$, then both would be true in a model $M\models T$, which is impossible.

Comment: Okay but can we prove directly it is consistent without using that existence of model arguement @AlexKruckman

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it!

Comment: @Sushil: You can disguise the model-theoretic argument as a syntactic one if you desperately want to: You can write down a purely syntactic definition by structural recursion, defining of a class of formulas that happens to coincide with the formulas that are true in $\{\{\varnothing\},{\in}\}$. Then prove that each of your axioms are in the class you have defined, and that the class is closed under each of the rules of inference of your logic. Conclude that every provable formula is in the class, and note that the class does not contain both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ for any $\phi$.

Comment: (This is not _quite_ as crazy a thing to do as @AlexKruckman's comment might give the impression of -- it is the most direct way to construct a consistency proof that works within Peano Arithmetic rather than set theory).

Comment: Sushil, can you clarify why you want to avoid talking about models?

Comment: The syntactic approach isn't crazy at all. It's like an argument used in textbooks (e.g., Mendelson) to show that the pure predicate calculus is consistent by transforming it into the propositional calculus. To handle this question, you'd strike out all the quantifiers, replace $x = y$ by $\top$ and $x \in y$  by $\bot$ and then show that the axioms are all propositional tautologies and that the inference rules relate tautologies to tautologies.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - for example, it is true in the structure with a single element $E$ (for emptyset), and where the binary relation is empty. It also has less stupid examples: given any transitive set $X$, the pair $(X, \in)$ is a model of this theory.

(Note that having a model easily implies consistency - this is the *soundness theorem*. More surprisingly, the converse is also true - this is the *completeness theorem*.)

---

Based on this, I'm not really sure you wrote the axioms you intend. Also, unless I'm misreading, (2) is the same as (1), and (3) follows from the semantics of equality in first-order logic. Did you mean to write other axioms?

Comment: It doesn't follow _solely_ from there being no existential quantifiers. For example the theory $\{(\forall x)(x\in x), (\forall x)(x\notin x)\}$ is not consistent.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point, fixed.

Comment: I think the theory is meant to work in a logic where equality is not a logical primitive (in other words, there are no logical axioms for $=$). Then axiom 3 together with 1 (or 2) guarantee that the $=$ predicate actually behaves like equality should.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. Okay first of all consistency I mean, can we prove there doesn't exist formula $\phi$ such that this theory implies $\phi$ as well as $\neg\phi$. And equality behaves like equality should. These are in my logical system axioms.

Comment: @Sushil: As Noah remarks, your theory _has a model_. You should already know that a theory that has a model is consistent (because every formula the theory can prove will be true in the model and it is impossible by definition for both $\phi$ and $\neg\phi$ to be true in the same structure) -- that is a consequence of the _soundness theorem_ and is the most important way to prove that a theory is consistent.

Comment: @Sushil: Your axiom 3 is one of the usual logical axioms for equality, so if your logic treats equality as a primitive, you don't even need to list it as an axiom. (And, as Noah notes, your axioms 1 and 2 are logically equivalent).